# css flex - is it possible to span over multiple lines?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

### note: it's not a duplicate, since i mentioned those solutions, and wrote that they not what i needed

I want to "grid" 3 elements using `flex`.
It is composed of three `div` elements:

- Two that takes 80% of the container element and with 50% height each, both stacked one above the other.
- One that is beside them, and takes 100% height and 20% width of the container.

like this:

```
 <div id="container">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>B</div>
   <div>C</div>
 </div>

 ------------------------
 |    |        B        |
 | A  -------------------
 |    |        C        |
 ------------------------
```

- I know how to do it with grid or with inner-container for `B` and `C`.
- I also know how to do it using `flex` with `flex-direction: column`.
- I know how to do it using `display:grid`

However, for some reason :-\ I have to do it using flex & row and without inner-container. any ideas?

Comment: *have to do it using flex & row and without inner-container* --> you cannot

Answer (score 0):

See if the below code works out for you. I am also attaching the output image.

```css
.container{
  display : flex;
  height : 300px;
  width : 500px;
}
.left{
  height: 100%;
  width : 20%;
  background-color : red;
}
.right{
  
  height : 100%;
  width : 80%;
}
.r{
  height : 50%;
  width : 100%;
}
.r1{
  background-color : yellow;
}
.r2{
  background-color : blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="r r1"></div>
    <div class="r r2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks. however, your solution is what I mentioned as `inner-container` (or wrapper..)

Comment: Then that isn't possible.. you see.. as flex is one directional layout